# Как добавить несколько меток на карту с помощью строки поиска

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Есть api яндекс карта, я использую с поиском для того чтобы пользователь мог ввести адрес и сразу на карте появляется метка. Это ок, все работает.

1. Но как можно сделать чтобы можно было несколько меток поставить сразу? Т.е несколько адресов сразу, один адрес ввел - метку поставил, второй адрес - вторая метка и все это видно на самой карте. Как можно это реализовать, можете подсказать если не трудно?
2. И как вывести каждый адрес в отдельный блок span чтобы можно было посмотреть как список какие адреса выбраны.

Вот код:

```js
ymaps.ready(function () {
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [55.755819, 37.617644],
            zoom: 12,
            controls: []
        }),
    // Создаем экземпляр класса ymaps.control.SearchControl
        mySearchControl = new ymaps.control.SearchControl({
            options: {
                noPlacemark: true
            }
        }),
    // Результаты поиска будем помещать в коллекцию.
        mySearchResults = new ymaps.GeoObjectCollection(null, {
            hintContentLayout: ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass('$[properties.name]')
        });
    myMap.controls.add(mySearchControl);
    myMap.geoObjects.add(mySearchResults);
    // При клике по найденному объекту метка становится красной.
   // mySearchResults.events.add('click', function (e) {
    //    e.get('target').options.set('preset', 'islands#redIcon');
  //  });
    // Выбранный результат помещаем в коллекцию.
    mySearchControl.events.add('resultselect', function (e) {
        var index = e.get('index');
        mySearchControl.getResult(index).then(function (res) {
           mySearchResults.add(res);
        });
    }).add('submit', function () {
            mySearchResults.removeAll();
        })
});
```

Comment: Про спан непонятно(

Answer (score 1):

Вы скопировали [правильный пример](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/custom_search_results?from=SO), но немного его недоредактировали. Вам нужно убрать  `mySearchResults.removeAll()` — этот метод как раз очищает список меток на карте перед следующим поиском. Если убрать эту строку, то метки прошлых поисков остаются на карте пока человек не обновит страницу.